# Ubuntu 15.10 can't see RAID 0 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid

I have 2 drives I've set up in RAID 0 (`/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` in Ubuntu). When I was running 15.04, I installed Ubuntu and a device appeared in `/dev/mapper`, which was the raid drive. After installing 15.10, the only device in `/dev/mapper` is one called "control".
Windows still sees the raid partition, so I know the raid drive works.

How can I get 15.10 to detect the raid drive?

PS. gparted says "cannot have a partition outside the disk" when I start it up, not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: try this command. `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`

Comment: If it was in /dev/mapper, it was a fake raid.  If you don't have to dual boot with Windows, then don't use fake raid; it's bad juju.  If you do, then the question is what kind?  If it is an Intel chipset/fakeraid, then those are now managed with `mdadm`, so you need to have that installed, instead of the older `dmraid`, which you still need for other fakeraids.

Answer (score 0):

Neil's solution of `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan` worked, but didn't stay around when I restarted.

The solution is to create a file `/etc/init.d/mountraid` with the following contents

```
#!/bin/sh

# scan for raid partitions
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan

# mount the drive here, using either mount or ntfs-3g
```

Then run `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mountraid` to allow it to be executed.

Finally, `sudo update-rc.d mountraid defaults` runs it on every boot.